# Meld has errors on OSX 10.10

Tags: python, macos, osx-yosemite, meld, difftool

I installed Meld 3.14.0 (current version as of this post) via Homebrew on OSX. Whenever I launch it, it gives me this:

```
Couldn't bind the translation domain. Some translations won't work.
'module' object has no attribute 'bindtextdomain'
2015-08-13 10:35:55.007 Python[2396:32534] *** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class
NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead.
```

Now it still launches and appears to work ok. I can view the diffs of files, which is what I care about mostly. When I exit though, I get the Mac OSX dialog "Python Quit Unexpectedly" as well as this from the command line:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.4.6/libexec/git-core/mergetools/meld: line 1:  2396 Segmentation fault: 11  "$merge_tool_path" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

**EDIT** I only get the segfault if I click the red X to close Meld. If I quit Python (what shows in the dock when Meld is open) via cmd+Q it closes cleanly.

The version of Meld I'm using is very recent, so I'm surprised I can't find more about this issue. My version of Python is 2.7.10.

Anyone else having this problem? I fear that when I want to actually do a merge and save I won't be able to due to the crash.

Comment: I'm also getting the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This product bug was fixed by now and version 3.14.2 succesfully installs on OS X 10.11 using `brew install homebrew/gui/meld`

In the future please use product issue tracker for product specific bugs. StackOverflow is not a replacement for usage of an issue tracker.

Check [meld issue tracker](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&bug_status=NEEDINFO&field0-0-0=product&list_id=111851&type0-0-0=substring&value0-0-0=meld)

Comment: Is `3.14.2` already in homebrew? I am getting `Error: homebrew/x11/meld 3.14.0 already installed` when I run `brew upgrade meld`. I previous ran `brew update`.